# Read file to determine the rules

Tags: python, csv

I have an excel file with user defined business rules as below:

```
Column_Name|Operator|Column_Value1|Operand|RuleID|Result
ABC        |   Equal|           12|    and|     1| 1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|    and|     1| 1
XYZ        |   Equal|           AD|       |     1| 1.5
ABC        |   Equal|           11|    and|     2| 1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|       |     2| 1.2
```

and so on. (just for formatting purpose have put | symbol).

Input file (CSV) will look like below:

```
ABC,CDE,XYZ
12,10,AD
11,10,AD
```

Goal here is to derive an output column called Result which needs to be looked up to the user defined business rule excel.

Output Expected:

```
ABC,CDE,XYZ,Result
12,10,AD,1.5
11,10,AD,1.2
```

I have so far tried to generate an `if` statement and trying to assign the entire `if/elif` statement to a function. So that I can pass it to below statement to apply the rules.

```
ouput_df['result'] = input_df.apply(result_func, axis=1)
```

When I have the function with manually coding the rules it works as shown below:

```
def result_func(input_df): 
    if (input_df['ABC'] == 12):
    return '1.25'
    elif (ip_df['ABC'] == 11):
    return '0.25'
    else:
    return '1'
```

Is this the right way of handling this scenario? If so how do I pass the entire dynamically generated `if/elif` to the function?

Comment: You could have a look at the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html) and then create a mapping between you business rules and the Python operator: `ops={
 'Equal':operator.eq 
}` Then apply that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Load rules table
rules_table = []
with open('rules.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
  for row in reader:
    rules_table.append([x.strip() for x in row.values()])

# Load CSV file into DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=",")

def rules_eval(row, rules):
  " Steps through rules table for appropriate value "
  def operator_eval(op, col, value):
    if op == 'Equal':
      return str(row[col]) == str(value)
    else:
      # Curently only Equal supported
      raise ValueError(f"Unsupported Operator Value {op}, only Equal allowed")

  prev_rule = '~'
  for col, op, val, operand, rule, res in rules:
    # loop through rows of rule table
    if prev_rule != rule:
      # rule ID changed so we can follow rule chains again
      ignore_rule = False

    if not ignore_rule:
      if operator_eval(op, col, val):
        if operand != 'and':
          return res
      else:
        # Rule didn't work for an item in group
        # ignore subsequent rules with this id
        ignore_rule = True

    prev_rule = rule

  return None

df['results'] = df.apply(lambda row: rules_eval(row, rules_table), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   ABC  CDE XYZ results
0   12   10  AD     1.5
1   11   10  AD     1.2
```

**Explanation**

df.apply - applies the `rules_eval` function to each row of the DataFrame.

The output is placed into column 'result' via

```
df['result'] = ...
```

**Handling Rule Priority**

*Change*

Added a Priority column to the rules_table so rules with the same RuleID are processed in order of priority.

Priority order decided by tuple ordering added to heap, currently

```
Priority, Column_Name, Operator, Column_Value, Operand, RuleID, Result
```

*Code*

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
from heapq import (heappush, heappop)

# Load CSV file into DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=",")

class RulesEngine():
  ###########################################
  # Static members
  ###########################################
  # Named tuple for rules
  fieldnames = 'Column_Name|Operator|Column_Value1|Operand|RuleID|Priority|Result'
  Rule = namedtuple('Rule', fieldnames.replace('|', ' '))
  number_fields = fieldnames.count('|') + 1

  ###########################################
  # members
  ###########################################
  def __init__(self, table_file):
    # Load rules table
    rules_table = []
    with open(table_file) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
      for row in reader:
        fields = [self.convert(x.strip()) for x in row.values() if x is not None]
        if len(fields) != self.number_fields:
          # Incorrect number of values
          error = f"Rules require {self.number_fields} fields per row, was given {len(fields)}"
          raise ValueError(error)

        rules_table.append([self.convert(x.strip()) for x in row.values()])
        #rules_table.append([x.strip() for x in row.values()])
    self.rules_table = rules_table

  def convert(self, s):
    " Convert string to (int, float, or leave current value) "
    try:
      return int(s)
    except ValueError:
      try:
        return float(s)
      except ValueError:
        return s

  def operator_eval(self, row, rule):
    " Determines value for a rule "
    if rule.Operator == 'Equal':
      return str(row[rule.Column_Name]) == str(rule.Column_Value1)
    else:
      # Curently only Equal supported
      error = f"Unsupported Operator {rule.Operator}, only Equal allowed"
      raise ValueError(error)

  def get_rule_value(self, row, rule_queue):
    " Value of a rule or None if no matching rule "
    found_match = True
    while rule_queue:
      priority, rule_to_process = heappop(rule_queue)

      if not self.operator_eval(row, rule_to_process):
        found_match = False
        break

    return rule_to_process.Result if found_match else None

  def rules_eval(self, row):
    " Steps through rules table for appropriate value "
    rule_queue = []
    for index, r in enumerate(self.rules_table):
      # Create named tuple with current rule values
      current_rule = self.Rule(*r)

      if not rule_queue or \
          rule_queue[-1][1].RuleID == current_rule.RuleID:
        # note: rule_queue[-1][1].RuleID is previous rule
        # Within same rule group or last rule of group
        priority = current_rule.Priority

        # heap orders rules by pririty 
        #   (lowest numbers are processed first)
        heappush(rule_queue, (priority, current_rule))

        if index < len(self.rules_table)-1:
          continue    # not at last rule, so keep accumulating

      # Process rules in the rules queue
      rule_value = self.get_rule_value(row, rule_queue)
      if rule_value:
        return rule_value
      else:
        # Starting over with new rule group
        rule_queue = []
        priority = current_rule.Priority
        heappush(rule_queue, (priority, current_rule))

    # Process Final queue if not empty
    return self.get_rule_value(row, rule_queue)

# Init rules engine with rules from CSV file
rules_engine = RulesEngine('rules.csv')

df['results'] = df.apply(rules_engine.rules_eval, axis=1)
print(df)
```

*Data Table*

```
ABC,CDE,XYZ
12,10,AD
11,10,AD
12,12,AA
```

*Rules Table*

```
Column_Name|Operator|Column_Value1|Operand|RuleID|Priority|Result
ABC        |   Equal|           12|    and|     1|        2|1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|    and|     1|        1|1
XYZ        |   Equal|           AD|    and|     1|        3|1.5
ABC        |   Equal|           11|    and|     2|        1|1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|    foo|     2|        2|1.2
ABC        |   Equal|           12|    foo|     3|        1|1.8
```

*Output*

```
 ABC  CDE XYZ results
0   12   10  AD     1.5
1   11   10  AD     1.2
2   12   12  AA     1.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your response DarrylG. But my problem here is reading the excel file to find out the rules which I'm converting it to an If statement. After that how do I pass it to the function. For example in my initial post if you see the excel business rule, the if conditions that will be dynamically obtained will look like this, if ('ABC' == 12 and 'CDE'] == 10 and XYZ = 'AD'): return '1.25' elif ('ABC' == 11 and 'CDE' == 10): return '1.2'. Let says if I'm able to generate this dynamically by reading the excel. How do I pass this statement to the function?

Comment: @pythoner--thanks for the explanation.  Updated my answer with a parser `rules_eval` that goes through the rules table to determine the appropriate value.

Comment: thank you so much,  you are great. Just have couple of questions, 1. If my rules_table is xlsx instead of csv is there an equivalent excel.DictReader? 2. If i introduce a new field - subrule to identify the order within rule, is there a way i can exit out of that rule based on the subrule instead of checking for "and" ?

Comment: @pythoner-- 1. Suggest trying [read_excel](https://www.journaldev.com/33306/pandas-read_excel-reading-excel-file-in-python) for Excel workbooks (rather than CSV). 2. Sure, but would have to know more about desired input and behavior.

Comment: @pythoner-are you asking how woud you have a subrule column, such as subrule 3,1,2,2,1 that goes with RuleID column which has values 1, 1, 1, 2, 2?  The meaning is For RuleID 1, we have subrules sequence 3,1,2 and for rule 2 we have subrule sequence 2, 1.  We want to apply the rules for 1 in the order 1, 2, 3 of the subrules.  Is this sort of what you meant?

Comment: yes that is correct. In our case Rule 1 will have subrule 1,2 and 3. So when I'm looping in instead of checking if there is "and" I need to check if that is the maximum sub rule for that rule and exit.

Comment: @pythoner--okay, got it.  Let's see how quickly I can give you an updated answer.

Comment: @pythoner--added an update.  Called the new column Priority (you can change that).  Rules with the same RuleID are processed in order of Priority (lowest number first).  It's okay if rules have the same priority (random which it selects first in that case).  This should meet your criteria of processing all rules up to the highest number, but by using a priority queue, it processing the rules in priority order.

Comment: @pythoner-let me check the update for errors before using, but it shows the idea.

Comment: You are awesome. One clarification, when I add one more rule with rule - 3 and priority - 1 (just only one priority) that rule is not being evaluated rather it returns none for the matching record. I'm trying to figure out what could be the reason. And for the priority can i do an combination of rule and priority ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214269/discussion-between-darrylg-and-pythoner).

Comment: Hi DarrylG, have an question related to operand in the rules table. What if I have a value "or" instead of "and" with open and closed parenthese?

Comment: @pythoner--I think "or" would be easy.  Regarding parens are you thinking of complex boolean expressions?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My rules table will look something like this. In below example, first rule should evaluate like ABC=12 and (CDE = 10 or XYZ = AD).
Column_Name|Operator|Column_Value1|Openpar|Operand|closepar|RuleID|Priority|Result
ABC        |   Equal|           12|       |and|   |  1|        2|1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|  (    |or |   |  1|        1|1
XYZ        |   Equal|           AD|       |   | ) |  1|        3|1.5
ABC        |   Equal|           11|       |and|   |  2|        1|1
CDE        |   Equal|           10|       |foo|   |  2|        2|1.2

Comment: @pythoner--at this point wouldn't it be simpler to redesign the rules table?  Perhaps just two columns: 1) trigger expression column and 2) value column.  The trigger expression column could be complex compressions such as `ABC==12 and (CDE == 10 or XYZ == AD)`  We return the result from the value column of the first trigger expression that is true. Seems this would be easier to create and maintain and evaluate than the rules table with lots of different column types (i.e. Column_Name, Priority, Openpar, closepar, Equal, etc.).  What do you think?

Comment: Hi DarrylG—thanks for your suggestion. The rules table is owned and governed by business team. And they wanted to have this broken into this specific design so that it is easier for them build the rules and review them. Does it make sense?

Comment: @pythoner--I don't understand your example with parens (from 2 days ago).  For rules with ruleID = 1, I assume we would assemble the expression in order of Priority (i.e. 1, 2, 3).  However, this is different from your claim since this creates  `(CDE = 10 or ABC = 12 and XYZ = AD)`.  While if we assemble by consecutive row number we get `ABC = 12 and (CDE = 12 or XYZ = AD)` which matches your claim.  Which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry DarrylG, my bad. Have updated the rules table below. To your point the rules should like this - 1st rule ABC=12 and (CDE = 10 or XYZ = AD), 2nd rule ABC = 11 or CDE = 10. Column_Name|Operator|Column_Value1|Openpar|Operand|closepar|RuleID|Priority|Result ABC | Equal| 12| |and| | 1| 1|1
CDE | Equal| 10| ( |or | | 1| 2|1
XYZ | Equal| AD| | | ) | 1| 3|1.5
ABC | Equal| 11| |or| | 2| 1|1
CDE | Equal| 10| || | 2| 2|1.2

Comment: @pythoner--under 1st rule: if ABC = 12 and CDE = 10, then the value is 1 (XYZ ignored). While if ABC = 12 and CDE != 10, XYZ = 'AD' then value is 1.5.  Is this correct?  Meaning we can just consider the overall expression, but the value of sub-expressions.  Perhaps we should open a private chat.

Comment: For the first rule ABC should be 12 and either CDE = 10 or XYZ = AD then the value should be 1.5.Have put some some examples below.                                                                     
ABC,CDE,XYZ
12,10,AD    -> 1.5
11,10,AD    -> 1.2
12,12,AD   -> 1.5
12,10,AA   -> 1.2
13,11,AD  -> no match                                                                                            
I was looking for an private chat conversation and couldn't figure out (not sure if I dont have access) if you can create one that will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @pythoner--that seems inconsistent with how I thought the rules table worked.  For instance, with a simpler table: ABC       | Equal   | 12         |        |or    |        | 1     | 1     |1
CDE       | Equal   | 10         |        |or    |        | 1     | 2     |1.5.  If ABC = 12, won't the value between 1.  While if ABC != 12, but CDE = 10, won't the value be 1.5?  Although the overall rules is ABC = 12 or CDE = 10, don't we report the value once the rule is True rather than the having to wait for the entire rule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218233/discussion-between-pythoner-and-darrylg).

Comment: @pythoner--sent you a message in chat.

Comment: @pythoner--sent a message in private chat earlier about an update to code.  Sending this in case you didn't see that message.

Comment: @pythoner-sent a message in private chat.

Comment: DarrylG -- sent a message in private chat.

Comment: @pythoner-sent you a question in chat.

Comment: @ DarrylG -- sent a message in chat

Comment: @ DarrylG -- sent a message in chat.

Comment: Hope you are doing well. Have an question related to the rules engine https://github.com/gurganious/rule_engine/blob/master/json/main.py. I have input data coming in with zeros prefixed, so the map_strip function converts this as int. Is the better way to handle will be to check if the first char of string is not zero?

Comment: @DarrylG--The second problem is when an integer column is sent with some null values the column is treated as float in the map_strip function.

Comment: @pythoner--regarding the prefix with 0's: are the values not ints?

Comment: @pythoner--regarding null-values: they become nan which only exists in float.  When you have a int column with null entries: what value should be used?

Comment: @DarrylG--For the null values it needs to be Nan but the dtype assigned to that particular column changes as float64 instead of int and even the values changes (eg: if the input record was 1 it changes to 1.0)

Comment: @DarrylG--Regarding the prefix 0's, we have input column coming in with prefix 0 (eg: 0003343878, 0867838) but when I read_csv and pass it on to map_strip function it strips the leading 0's (3343878, 867838). I don't think we had this scenario in our example.

Comment: @pythoner--are these to be interpreted as an int?  If so, then the int value of 0003343878 equals 3343878 (i.e. dropping the prefix is fine). So, since these are ints I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227907/discussion-between-pythoner-and-darrylg).

Comment: @DarrylG--sent a message in chat.